# Ashkenazic Rabbanim who hold Kitniyot are batel berov lechatchilah before pesach

Tags: halacha, minhag, passover, kitniyos-semigrain-legume, bitul-batel-null

Are there any Ashkenazic poskim who hold, like R.Yitzchak Abadi, that kitniyot are batel berov lechatchilah before pesach, thus allowing Ashkenazim to drink regular coke with corn syrup, for example, as well as many other foods?

Comment: Who holds it isn't batel berov? You should be asking about bittul lechatchilah before pesach.

Comment: @seth I think the two questions are independently valuable.

Comment: @DoubleAA I was just making his question smoother. I tihnk he was only asking one question and assuming that the answer to it would also answer another question which motivated the one that was asked.

Comment: Yishaq, feel free the ask the motivating question - "(Why) can't Ashkenazim drink Coke on Pesah if the corn syrup is Batel?" separately.

Comment: See shu"t Dovev Mesharim 2:2, and [Yesodei Yeshurun 6:pg 414](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=4175&st=&pgnum=414&hilite=)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK that kitniyot is nullified in a majority is universally agreed upon. The Rama ([OC 453:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49627&st=&pgnum=95)) writes that we do not forbid a mixture into which kitniyot fell, and the Mishna Berura there notes that obviously this means that there must be at least a majority of non-kitniyot and that if any piece of kitniyot is visible (*nikkar*) one must pick it out.

Comment: NOTE: The conclusions drawn by the OP that my answer allows Ashkenazim to drink regular coke are not straightforward and are not addressed in this post because he didn't ask about them.

Comment: So why do most Ashkenazim require kosher le Pesach coke?

Comment: @Yishaq Probably because we don't nullify things on purpose. You can ask a question about it if you want, cf http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/166155.

Comment: @DoubleAA, the reason Ashkenazim drink milk, though, is that before Pesah it isn't Asur, and it's therefore Batel in a state of Heter.

Comment: @SethJ And one more factor: there isn't any wheat in milk anyway and no one wants there to be any wheat in milk.

Comment: @double aa, that's really a factor? Fact, maybe, but I thought the Halachic consideration was that it was Batel before it became prohibited.

Comment: @SethJ You're discussing why _chametz bemashehu_ doesn't apply, not why _bittul lechatchilah_ doesn't apply. Not wanting wheat there is very different from purposefully putting in loads of corn syrup.

Comment: @doubleaa , its not universally accepted since the Sdei Chemed held that one needs to take out the kitnios

Comment: Also see Shulchan Aruch Harav siman 464:2 from the Piskei Tshuvos

Comment: @sam I wrote if you can see it to take it out. Does the Sdei Chemed require more than that?